# bxslider image too large when page first load

Tags: javascript, css

I am using bxslider and when the slider loads the images insides loads in full size at the same time, which makes the website looks odd. There are about 5 images within the slider and when the page loads/refresh, they all appears in full size before resizing.

the width has been set to 100% if I control the size width & height in the below code things will not look right in mobile/tablet devices so the size needs to be adaptive to all screens.

This is the code currently used:

```
.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
    padding: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
}
.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
       /* display: block; */
}
```

I hope if anyone can help and stop the images from over scaling when page loads and keeping in mind all screen sizes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [bxSlider's preloadImages option](http://bxslider.com/options) to load all the slider's images before processing the slider:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  preloadImages: 'all'
});
```

(change `.bxslider` to the appropriate class of your slider's instance…)